# Can I Convert a String to a List with a generic type?

Tags: java, list, generics, casting

I am trying to write a function that splits a string by a delimiter and then returns a list of values of a generic type derived from the split segments.

```java
public static <T> List<T> splitToList(String toParse, String delimiter, Class<T> cls) {
    String[] values = toParse.split(delimiter);
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        list.add(cls.cast(values[i]));
    }
    return list;
}
```

My code doesnt work for `cls = Integer.class`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you mean by "My code doesnt work?" Could you give us an example of how you call the function, and what is the expected output vs. what you get?

Comment: When you split the string you get little strings. Don't expect `cast` to magically convert them to another class. What if the class was `Dog`? How do you convert a `String` to a `Dog`? You need to define a conversion method.

Comment: Anyway, you can't just cast String to any random type. How do you expect it to behave when someone inputs `MySuperComplexObjectHashMap.class`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot generically cast java `String`s to any kind of POJO. You need to define, how the Strings are 'parsed' into objects. As you want a generic list, you need a generic parsing method. I'd suggest the following:

```java
public static <T> List<T> splitParseToList(String input, String delimiter, Function<String, T> parser) {
    String[] segments = StringUtils.split(input, delimiter);
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String segment : segments) {
        String unparsed = StringUtils.strip(segment);
        // This is the step you missed (The conversion from String to 'actual' object):
        T value = parser.apply(unparsed);
        result.add(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This allows you to specify the parsing function with which to convert the strings into something else:

```java
String test = "1, 2, 4, 8";
List<Integer> list = splitParseToList(test, ",", Integer::parseInt);
System.out.println(list);
```

I used apache's `StringUtils` here. It is open source.

Be aware, that this method is not robust to 'bad input'. I will leave that up to you to ensure the input is handled as you desire.